# Java: Trying to add byte bigger than 127 to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer, randomaccessfile

So pretty much in my program I'm reading a filesystem using RandomAccessFile, and then I locate byte 1080 and return the value, which in this case is 239.

Now, I'm using a ByteBuffer and want to add this value to the ByteBuffer, but it now becomes -17 for obvious reasons rather than 239. Is there ANY way to add this to a ByteBuffer/byte array by keeping it's original value? I want to eventually convert it to a hexadecimal value so I don't want the value to change.

Not sure if this makes any sense, I understand that byte only goes up to 127 in Java? Any way to add up to 255?

Comment: Just consider it unsigned when you print it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a byte bigger than 127 in Java. They are signed, so their values are -128..127. All you are seeing here is sign extension.

Comment: -17 and 239 have exactly the same bits if you put them in an 8-bit byte. It shouldn't cause problems, although when you print it it looks weird - one way to avoid is to print `byteValue & 0xff`. If your code has problems as a result of this, please post a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: There also is `Byte.toUnsignedInt(someByte)`. But `String.format("%02x", (byte)-17)` will do (`ef`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sum is extending passed 127 and setting the sign bit.

```java
      byte a = 121;
      byte b = 110;

      byte c = (byte) (a + b);
      System.out.println(c + " " + (c & 0xFF));

      b = (byte) 255;

      c = (byte) (a + b);
      System.out.println(c + " " + (c & 0xFF) + " " + (byte) 376);
```

Prints

```
      -25 231
      120 120 120
```

If one wants to sum up multiple values where the sign extension might cause problems it is best to cast the values to a wider type (byte to int or int to long) and mask off the sign extension prior to adding.

```java
      byte a = 121; 
      b = (byte) 255;
      int d = a + (b & 0xFF);  // mask off sign with int mask.
      System.out.println(d);

      long e = 0;
      int v = -1;
      e = e + (v & 0xFFFF_FFFFL); // mask off sign with long mask
      System.out.println(e);
```

Prints

```
      376
      4294967295
```